# Project window is missing in keymap settings in Intellij Idea 2023.1.2

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij Idea, I would like to assign a keyboard shortcut to `Project window`, for example Cmd+1.

I go to settings -> keymap -> search project window.

expected result: display `project window` so that I can assign shortcut to it

actual result: there is no `project window`.

I am using

IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-231.9011.34, built on May 16, 2023

Macbook Pro, 15-inch, 2018

MacOS 13.3.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to help -> show log in Finder -> open `idea.log` with editor like vim.

Search `window`, and I saw exceptions like below

```
2023-05-17 09:25:51,431 [  13694] SEVERE - #c.i.o.w.i.ToolWindowManagerImpl - Cannot invoke (class=FigWindowListener, method=toolWindowsRegistered, topic=tool window events)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot invoke (class=FigWindowListener, method=toolWindowsRegistered, topic=tool window events)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.invokeListener(MessageBusImpl.kt:657)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.deliverMessage(MessageBusImpl.kt:415)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.pumpWaiting(MessageBusImpl.kt:394)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.access$pumpWaiting(MessageBusImpl.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessagePublisher.invoke(MessageBusImpl.kt:454)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy95.toolWindowsRegistered(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer.postEntryProcessing(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:155)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer.postEntryProcessing$default(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:152)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer.createAndLayoutToolWindows(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:138)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer.access$createAndLayoutToolWindows(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:45)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer$createAndLayoutToolWindows$1.invokeSuspend(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
Caused by: com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.RuntimeExceptionWithAttachments: Current thread: Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-48,5,main] 1688829040 (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()=false)
```

Something wrong with ToolWindowManagerImpl. And it comes from class FigWindowListener

So go to settings -> Plugins -> disable plugin called `Fig` -> restart Intellij Idea. Problem solved.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right place for this information? It feels like a bug in plugin, and I'd suggest filing an issue to this plugin if it's opensource, or writing to support otherwise.

Comment: Looks like it is a known issue https://github.com/withfig/fig/issues/2469